# ReactJS: How to change Text value on button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, text, ecmascript-6

I am creating a form in my App and need to add a quantity field in it. I have added a `<Text>` component from [informed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/informed) to add quantity field and used buttons to add increment and decrement feature.

But I am not able to set Text component value on button click. It seems like  I can only set `initialValue` for `<Text>` component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { arrayOf, number, shape, string } from 'prop-types';

import classify from 'src/classify';
import defaultClasses from './quantity.css';
import { Text } from 'informed';

class Quantity extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        classes: shape({
            root: string,
            increment_button: string,
            decrement_button: string,
            quantity_input: string
        }),
        items: arrayOf(
            shape({
                value: number
            })
        )
    };

    state = {
        quantity: 1,
        show: true,
        max: 9999,
        min: 1
    };

    incrementQty = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            if(prevState.quantity < this.state.max) {
                return {
                    quantity: parseInt(prevState.quantity) + 1
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        });
        /*this.setState({ quantity: parseInt(this.state.quantity) + 1 });*/
    };
    decrementQty = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            if(prevState.quantity > this.state.min) {
                return {
                    quantity: parseInt(prevState.quantity) - 1
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        });
        /*this.setState({ quantity: parseInt(this.state.quantity) - 1 });*/
    };
    setQuantity = quantity => this.setState({ quantity });
    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({quantity: event.target.value});
    };

    render() {
        const { classes, ...restProps } = this.props;
        console.log(this.state.quantity);
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
            <span onClick={this.decrementQty} className={classes.decrement_button}>-</span>
            <Text
                initialValue = {`${this.state.min}`}
                className={classes.quantity_input}
                field="quantity"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.quantity}
                label=""
            />
            <span onClick={this.incrementQty} className={classes.increment_button}>+</span>
            </div>
    );
    }
}

export default classify(defaultClasses)(Quantity);
```

I have tried using `value` prop but its not working. If I am using uncontrolled html `<input>` field, the buttons and quantity increment decrement works but I don't want to use `<input>` element with my form.

Comment: from which library you are using this <Text /> component

Comment: As stated in question, I am using informed. https://www.npmjs.com/package/informed

Comment: using hook method look here https://joepuzzo.github.io/informed/?path=/story/hooks--useformapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, informed `Text` doesn't have a prop `value`, I found a trick on how to set the value of the `Text` on a click of a button.

You can create a ref using `React.createRef` to your Text then set the value via this ref.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = React.createRef();
  }
  state = {
    min: 10
  };
  changeQt = () => {
    this.ref.current.value = 20;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Text
          initialValue={`${this.state.min}`}
          field="quantity"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          label=""
          ref={this.ref}
        />
        <button onClick={this.changeQt}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[**Demo here.**](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-wind-06lh5)

Comment: Thank you for this demo. I am trying to implement but facing below warning `Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?` and an error where I am assigning value `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`, Would you guide me on this.?

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for that error, so I can help you!?

Comment: I have created a demo https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-moon-3718g but here its working. Thank you for the solution, I'll check my code now and will debug the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps you. You're welcome mate

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your code should be

```
 onChange={quantity => this.handleChange(quantity)}
```

and your code to handle state update

```
onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you tony for the answer but it does not update textbox value when I click on button.

Comment: `onChange={quantity => this.handleChange(quantity)}` does the same as `onChange={this.handleChange}` except that in the first case the function is recreated on every render..

Comment: I have updated question with my complete file code. As you can see I have used console.log to get quantity value and I can get correct values when I click on inc/dec buttons.